# I want to edit the auto text adding feature in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to edit the content of the code which is being added on pressing ctrl + space. in eclipse.
For example lets say I am using a try catch block
when I write cat then ctrl + space what eclipse does is this

```
[code]
catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    }
[/code]
```

this is the default behavior. What I want is that how can i change this behavior. Instead of default behavior I want the catch block like this on pressing ctrl+space

```
[code]
catch (Exception e) {
    print exception
    }
[/code]
```

I hope you got my question. Now a solution please.Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define and change the templates in the Preferences dialog under Java -> Editor -> Templates.